# Browsing a package in ghci

Tags: haskell, package, ghci

I have a project set up via `stack` and am importing a package dependency. I see that the package downloaded/installed successfully, so I had hoped that the REPL spawned by `stack ghci` would let me explore this package. To my surprise, there doesn't seem to be any sort of command for browsing a package. You can use `:browse` to look through a *module*, but I don't seem to have any way to see which modules are exposed by this package.

Is there any way to inspect a *package* in `ghci`? And if not, are there other ways to inspect a package? I know there are websites which provide documentation, but I want to ensure the information I'm seeing matches the actual version of the package which is installed.

Comment: I only know `:! cabal info packageName`-- I'm not sure whether there's an internal command for that.

Comment: An external command might be ok. However, I tried your suggestion and get this message: cabal: Use of GHC's environment variable GHC_PACKAGE_PATH is incompatible with Cabal. Use the flag --package-db to specify a package database (it can be used multiple times).

Comment: I am able to run that _outside_ of `ghci`, and it seems to get me what I want.

Comment: `ghc-pkg describe <package>` is another external command that displays the exposed modules. Or even `ghc-pkg field <package> exposed-modules`. You can even define a GHCi macro: `:def pkg (\ pkgname -> System.Process.system ("ghc-pkg field " ++ pkgname ++ " exposed-modules") >> return "")`. And then say `:pkg <pkgname` at the GHCi prompt.

Comment: @kosmikus, I didn't know about the ability to create macros! That should be posted as an answer.

Comment: Can you make a package that does this?